# Get property name from expression for array property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, tree, expression

Basically I'm trying to do very simple thing, but I can't figure out, how to do this.
I'm trying to get Property name from expresion, for example for this expressions I want to get results:

- `PropertyName(e => e.Easy)` = "Easy"
- `PropertyName(e => e.Not.So.Easy)` = "Not.So.Easy"
- `PropertyName(e => e.ImLost[i])` where i is variable in for-loop = "ImLost[0]", "ImLost[1]", ...

For first two it's relativelly easy, but for the third one I'm lost, but I'm think that I can't be the first one, who want to achieve the same thing. Do you have any advice or idea?
Signature for PropertyName method is following `static string PropertyName<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expr) where T : class`.

Comment: How are you currently implementing `PropertyName`? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will handle all three cases:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PropertyNameFromExpression
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PropertyNameTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCanGetEasyExpression()
        {
            string propertyName = PropertyName<Source>(e => e.Easy);
            Assert.AreEqual("Easy", propertyName);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCanGetNotSoEasyExpression()
        {
            string propertyName = PropertyName<Source>(e => e.Not.So.Easy);
            Assert.AreEqual("Not.So.Easy", propertyName);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCanGetArrayExpressionWithConstantIndex()
        {
            string propertyName = PropertyName<Difficult>(e => e.ImLost[3]);
            Assert.AreEqual("ImLost["+3+"]", propertyName);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCanGetArrayExpressionWithVariableIndex()
        {
            int i = 3;
            string propertyName = PropertyName<Difficult>(e => e.ImLost[i]);
            Assert.AreEqual("ImLost[" + i + "]", propertyName);
        }

        public string PropertyName<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, int>> expression)
        {
            return PropertyName(expression.Body);
        }

        private string PropertyName(Expression expression)
        {
            if (expression is BinaryExpression)
            {
                return PropertyName(expression as BinaryExpression);
            }
            if (expression is ConstantExpression)
            {
                return (expression as ConstantExpression).Value.ToString();
            }
            MemberExpression memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression.Expression is MemberExpression)
            {
                return PropertyName(memberExpression.Expression) + "." + memberExpression.Member.Name;
            }
            if (memberExpression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown Expression type:"+expression.GetType().Name);
            }
            if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
            {
                var f = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression).Compile();
                object value = f.DynamicInvoke();
                return value.ToString();
            }
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }
        private string PropertyName(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(binaryExpression.Left.Type))
            {
                return PropertyName(binaryExpression.Left) + "[" + PropertyName(binaryExpression.Right) + "]";
            }
            return PropertyName(binaryExpression.Left) + "." + PropertyName(binaryExpression.Right);
        }

    }

    public class Source
    {
        public int Easy { get; set; }
        public Level2 Not { get; set; }
    }

    public class Level2
    {
        public Level3 So { get; set; }
    }
    public class Level3
    {
        public int Easy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Difficult
    {
        public int[] ImLost { get;set; }
    }
}
```